# What are the life support systems in the reconditioning tubes?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Is that any explanation as to how the prisoners survived in the reconditioning tubes.

The substance looks to be in a very viscus liquid state when it goes around the body and hardening only on the outer shell.

Anything out there that mentions this?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive given the quote from the official novelisation. Is there anything else you'd like to see on this one before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mentioned briefly in the film's novelisation. Apparently it's a "Preservative/Petrifying gel".

> Preservative gel began to fill the cells, spurring the condemned rebels to panic. Tor-An pounded uselessly at the translucent walls of his sarcophagus, while Faora screamed in rage. Nam-Ek required a larger cell than the others, but even his mammoth fists were unable to break through the rectangular force field that contained him
>
> ...
>
> Lara watched as the petrifying gel congealed, revealing the rebels, frozen within their cells—as immobile as statues. They were preserved in various states of fear and anger. A look of utter malice contorted Zod’s rigid features.

With no further description of the science behind it, I think we can safely assume that the gel is largely made out of purest plotonium, a rare element used only by writers.